# Asp net core SignalR websocket connection time more then 1 second

Tags: .net-core, websocket, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I created dot net core SignalR client using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr
Using StartAsync connection takes more than 1 second. 
That is too long.
How can we reduce start time? Any parameters to tweak?

Comment: 1)The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) you shared is for ASP.NET SignalR, not for  [ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). 2)How do you measure the time taken for code execution and find it takes more than 1 second? 3)Please check which transport (WebSockets, Server-Sent Events and Long Polling) is used.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for response and the rectified link.
Solution is using ASP.NetCore and transport is configured to use WebSocket ONLY.
Server side (Startup/ Configure)

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapHub<LiveHub>("/signalr/livehub", options =>
      {
        options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
      });
  });
```

Console Client application was built as per: 
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/signalr/dotnet-client/sample/SignalRChatClient
Under Client

```
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .WithUrl("http://localhost:xxxx/signalr/livehub", options =>
  {
    options.SkipNegotiation = true;
    options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
  })
  .Build();
```

Time for code execution was calculated on client, on

```
await connection.StartAsync();
```

With multiple test cases, average connection time hovers around 900msec to 1200 msec.
This is a very long time.